# How do I make an ArrayList not a pointer

Tags: java, pointers, arraylist, reference

So, I'm writing this program simply to simulate dice rolls for probability reasons.  And I've found the problem, I know what it's doing, I just don't know how to fix it.

The main issue (besides poor coding) is that my `succ` variable is pointing to or referencing my `points` variable.  Therefore when it's time to get averages, I get averages for the culmination of all the sets of dicests instead of an average of each diceset. Clearing the `points` variable is supposed to let me start with a fresh ArrayList, but it also clears all information that is supposed to be in `succ`

To anyone interested in running this program, enter in dicesets like this: 3d6. It was a personal choice, I could make it account for any number of n-sided dice but for my purposes I only need 5 max.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DiceThing {
  static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  static int trials;
  static String bleh = new String("hurr");
  static ArrayList < String > dice = new ArrayList < String > ();
  static ArrayList < Integer > roll = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
  static ArrayList < Integer > points = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
  static ArrayList < Integer > num = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
  static ArrayList < Integer > type = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
  static ArrayList < ArrayList < Integer >> succ = new ArrayList < ArrayList < Integer >> ();

  static Random rand = new Random();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter any number of dicesets. Enter 0 to stop");
    while (!bleh.equals("0")) {
      System.out.println("Enter diceset: ");
      bleh = scan.nextLine();
      if (!bleh.equals("0"))
        dice.add(bleh);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter number of trials: ");
    trials = scan.nextInt();

    for (String i: dice) {
      num.add(Integer.parseInt(i.substring(0, 1)));
      type.add(Integer.parseInt(i.substring(2)));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.size(); i++) { //count place in dicesets
      for (int j = 0; j < trials; j++) { //count trials
        for (int k = 0; k < num.get(i); k++) //count number of dice in the diceset
          roll.add(rand.nextInt(type.get(i)) + 1);

        points.add(countSuccess(roll, type.get(i)));
        System.out.println(roll.toString() + points.toString());

        roll.clear();
      }
      succ.add(points);
      points.clear();
      System.out.println(succ.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("Average success of dice sets:");
    for (ArrayList < Integer > i: succ) {
      System.out.println(average(i));
    }
  }

  public static int countSuccess(ArrayList < Integer > list, int high) {
    int suc = 0, temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      if (list.get(i) >= 5)
        suc++;
      if (list.get(i) == high)
        suc++;
      if (list.get(i) >= 10) {
        temp = rand.nextInt(type.get(i)) + 1;
        roll.add(temp);
        list.add(temp);
      }
    }
    return suc;

  }

  private static double average(ArrayList < Integer > marks) {
    Integer sum = 0;
    if (!marks.isEmpty()) {
      for (Integer mark: marks) {
        sum += mark;
      }
      return sum.doubleValue() / marks.size();
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

The issue is occurring here though the origin may be elsewhere.

```
succ.add(points);
points.clear();
System.out.println(succ.toString());
```

I probably didn't explain very well and if that's the case then let me know.  Any help and explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: could you eleborate your problem a little bit? it´s unknown from the question what your actuall problem is.

Comment: Why don't you just make `points` reference a new `ArrayList` after you add it to `succ`, instead of calling `clear`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
succ.add(new ArrayList(points));
```

If I understood you correctly, you want to separate a list in your list from the origin one, don't you?

If so then just make a new list and copy values there from the origin collection. A constructor `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` will help.

After that, the `points.clear()` call won't change a value in the list.
Only `succ.get(index).clear()` will clear it.

Answer (score 0):

My testing has found this to work:

```
succ.add(new ArrayList(points));
points.clear();
```

Assuming I understand the behavior that the OP intended:

- points is an ArrayList of successes from the trial
- succ contains ArrayLists of points from each trial